# Convert column with minutes and seconds in seconds only in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, timestamp, lubridate

my dataframe have this format:

```
name <- c("Carlos", "Matthew", "Toth", "Mike", "Joseph", "Andrey")

time <- c("79:45","78","74:45","65:30","64","57")

myexample <- cbind.data.frame(name, time)

> myexample
     nane  time
1  Carlos 79:45
2 Matthew    78
3    Toth 74:45
4    Mike 65:30
5  Joseph    64
6  Andrey    57
```

How to convert time column with two formats ("79:45" and "78") in seconds?

the time column is in the character format :(

As output:

```
> myexample
         nane  time
    1  Carlos 79:45
    2 Matthew 78:00
    3    Toth 74:45
    4    Mike 65:30
    5  Joseph 64:00
    6  Andrey 57:00
```

Comment: What are the units involved here?  Can you add this information to your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added more information on the issue!

Comment: @RonakShah added the output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `sub`:

```
myexample$time <- sub("^(\\d{1,})$", "\\1:00", myexample$time)
myexample

     name  time
1  Carlos 79:45
2 Matthew 78:00
3    Toth 74:45
4    Mike 65:30
5  Joseph 64:00
6  Andrey 57:00
```

### Demo

Normally the best thing to do here would be to parse your text times into some formal time type.  But since you are storing non standard values, where the minutes component can be greater than 60, I chose to leave it as text for the moment.

Comment: if my string have only one digit?

Answer (score 0):

An option can be using `grepl` to detect presence of `:` and appending `:00` in values `:` is not present.

```
myexample$time <- ifelse(grepl(":",myexample$time), as.character(myexample$time),
                       paste0(myexample$time, ":00"))

myexample    
#      name  time
# 1  Carlos 79:45
# 2 Matthew 78:00
# 3    Toth 74:45
# 4    Mike 65:30
# 5  Joseph 64:00
# 6  Andrey 57:00
```